# java.lang.ArrayStoreException in java.util.Hashset

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

Here is the stack trace :

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
        at java.util.HashMap.transfer(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.resize(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(Unknown Source)
```

Some observations :

1. Its an intermittent issue
2. JDK 1.6
3. CentOS 5.3

As I understand this error is intermittent I suspect it occurs whenever the HashSet (hence underlying HashMap) needs to resize itself. But not sure why this `ArrayStoreException`. Now what I want to know is

-What are the scenarios wherein this error can occur  ?

Comment: Have you tried to debug? You can attach jdk sources to your IDE and look at the exact line, where error occurs.

Comment: @Nikita, as mentioned, this error is intermittent, we could not reproduce it consistently hence debugging didn't help.

Comment: There is no way this can happen, must be a bug somewhere. Even hardware bugs.

Comment: What kind of JDK is this? OpenJDK?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, its the JDK from SUN/Oracle

Comment: I would log each object that has been added to the hashset, how many objects are you feeding with it?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, its in excess of a million String objects.

Comment: Could you try catching the exception in the client code to help you log what is being added to the HashSet?

Comment: @SimonNickerson, Yes we have added this code, so far this error hasn't shown up in the logs. I will update the question in case of  more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that you're trying to update the set from multiple threads concurrently. `HashSet` and `HashMap` aren't designed to be thread-safe - if you're going to access your set from multiple threads, you should use synchronization to prevent concurrent access.

That's just a guess, of course - without seeing your code I can't tell whether you *are* using multiple threads. It would go along with the intermittent side of things though...

Comment: the code does not run in a multi-threaded environment. We are seeing this when extremely large amount of data is loaded in the HashsSet.

Comment: @Santosh: Okay, in that case it sounds like a bug in the JRE. If you can log the order in which you add things to the set, you may be able to reproduce it - at which point life would be a lot easier.

Comment: we  have added to code the catch this exception and the object causing it. So far it hasn't shown in the logs. I will update the the question with more information we get when the error shows up in logs.

Comment: @Santosh: I would try to write an application which *just* tried to provoke this bug. Generate random objects and log them before adding, repeating with different random seeds until you find one which provokes the bug. I doubt that it's anything special about the single object - it'll be in some odd state beforehand.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, we are trying this approach to reproduce this issue.